Getting the right surface area raster layer
I am calculating the surface area of a raster file and even though I have tried to put it in all sorts of projections it still shows dg2. I have now used the projection equal earth greenwhich which shows its metric in meters, I still get these values. How can I calculate the surface area?



Where did you "put it in all sorts of projections"? You have to Warp/Reproject the raster to a projected CRS.

Yes I reprojected it to different CRS projections to see if there would be a result in m2. I tried world mercator, equal earth greenwhich and UTM zone 33N

And thank you for your answer!

I can see how many pixels are 1 though, maybe it would be best to calculate the pixel size? but maybe that will then also be stated in dg2

How did you reproject? I suspect you just changed the project CRS, but did not actually reproject the raster. Use Menu Raster -> Projections -> Warp (reproject), see: https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterprojections.html#warp-reproject

I had a reprojection issue in QGIS 3.36.0 on Win 10: when reprojecting (using algorithm Reproject layer from toolbox as well as export/save with a new CRS), QGIS does either not perform this task correctly and the output is still in the initial CRS, or the tool wrongly assigns a new CRS definition without reprojecting and the layer shows up in another part of the world. Did not have this issue with earlier versions, might be a bug? Testet for vector layers in EPSG:4326 (WGS 84), tried to reproject to EPSG:2056 (swiss grid). With the same data, reproject worked well with QGIS 3.34.2

See here if you don't have the same problem: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/482752/in-qgis-3-36-i-am-unable-to-reproject-vector-layers
