Reprojecting vector layer does not reproject in QGIS 3.36.0
Using QGIS 3.36.0 Maidenhead on Win10, I have a strange behaviour: Reprojecting vector layers (with Reproject layer) does reproject, but invariably to EPSG:4326, and with the wrong CRS definition assigned to the resulting layer: the one I chose in the Reproject Layer dialog window.
So A) the geometries are misplaced on the Earth and B) reprojecting to any other CRS than EPSG:4326 is not possible. As it seems (see screenshot) the wrong transformation is selected. However, I don't see an option to change that. And from the behaviour of earlier QGIS versions (where it still works fine), QGIS should automatically select the correct transformation.
When I export/save the layer with a new CRS, the layer is saved in the initial CRS, so no reprojection (and neither a wrong CRS definition is assigned). This means I have no option to reproject vector layers.
Seems like a bug to me: can someone reproduce the error?
How to reproduce:

Create random points in extent in EPSG:4326 or EPSG:3857
Menu Processing Toolbox Reproject Layer: reproject to EPSG:2056 (Swiss national grid) or EPSG:27700 (British national grid), depending on the initial extent.

The resulting layer is misplaced, see result in the screenshot below. Looking at the coordinate values, they are in lat/lon (!), so the layer is in fact reprojected to EPSG:4326 (WGS84), but with a wrong CRS definition assigned.
Reprojecting the initial (blue) layer results in a layer (red points) in EPSG:4326, but with CRS definition EPSG:2056 assigned to it:


In what format are your data ? some format will only accept EPSG:4326 (KML for exemple) as valid CRS...

I save it as Geopackage or temporary layer (the screenshot shows a temporary layer).

All I can say is it works on my machine :-) first upgrade to the latest version (3.36.3-Maidenhead) and try again in a new blank project.

and possibly don't start with 3875

I also started with 4326, to the same effect. Yes, I will try updating.

Using QGIS 3.36.3 and memory layer I can't reproduce the issue, the point reproject to Switzerland. The only difference I see with your setting is the transformation used, in my QGIS version I get "Inverse of Popular Visualisation Pseudo-Mercator + Inverse of CH1903+ to WGS 84 (1) + Swiss Oblique Mercator 1995" with an Accuracy of 1 (meters) and an area of use : "World., Liechtenstein; Switzerland."

Yes, I guess QGIS applies the wrong transformation, but I don't know why (and how to change).

Maybe try to set a default datum transformation in Option>CRS and Transforms>Coordinate Transforms or check that there is nothing wrong here...

Tried the same with random points in 4326 in England, reprojecting in British national grid (EPSG:27700), with the same result: misplaced layer with lat/lon coordinates, but with layer CRS definition EPSG:27700

@J.R Options / Coordinate Transforms is empty: https://i.sstatic.net/DaajgMN4.png This is the same in older QGIS versions, where I encounter no problems at all.

So it seem that your specific QGIS version/installation have problem with reprojection, I thing following @IanTurton suggestion of upgrading or reinstalling QGIS is the way to go....

I just tried with both QGIS 3.36.3, GDAL 3.4.1, PROJ 8.2.1 & EPSG database v10.041 (2021-12-03) in Ubuntu and QGIS 3.36.3 GDAL 3.9.0, PROJ 9.4.1 and EPSG database
v11.006 (2024-03-13) in a conda env and couldn't reproduce.

Meanwhile, I installed QGIS 3.36.3. Here, everything works well. So the problem is in 3.36.0 only.

This seems to be a bug in 3.36.0 - I could reproduce it on another system. I solved the problem by updating the the newest point release, QGIS 3.36.3. There, reprojection works as expected.
